# can i navigate to other View by textField didBeginEditing method ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c

When user tap on `textfield` so is there any way to open new `viewController`.

For example, `textFieldCountryCode` having already value set. now user try to change text at that time new `view` should be open and after select the option that `view` should be closed and control comes back to previous `viewController` with selected value should be set inside `textFieldCountryCode`.

Comment: try textfield value changes action method your problem solve

Comment: @IBAction func Textchanges(sender: AnyObject) {
        if txttext.text?.characters.count > 0 {
            //change your video write code.
        }
 }

Comment: you can set the drop down or `pickerView` like functionality in the case.

Comment: Javed Please check my answer and accept i8f it is ok

Answer (score 1):

You should use `pickerview` to pick value instead of new `viewcontroller` in this kind of functionality!

You can set `pickerview` as `inputview` of your `textfield`.

Then also if you want to use seperate viewcontroller then in `textFieldDidBeginEditing` method you can `present` that viewcontroller and you can use `delegate and protocol` to set value of textfield which is choosen from viewcontroller!

Answer (score 1):

You can do using passing data using delegate while select country from CountryViecController.

try this code snippet

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
    if (textField.tag == 100) {
        ViewController *videoVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"videoVC"];
        videoVC.delegate = self;
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:videoVC animated:YES];

        return NO;
    }
    return YES;

}

// delegate  method for video controller, here you get selected country 
-(void)selectedString:(NSString *)selectedCountry{
    NSLog(@"%@",selectedCountry);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can push to `nextViewController` by using `textFieldDidBeginEditing` method see below code:

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
    [_myTextfield resignFirstResponder];
    TestVc *myVc = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil]instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TestVc"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:myVc animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This kind of functionality can be done by two approach :

**First** : via `pickerview`

You need to add `your_textfield.inputView = your_pickerview;`
and you can done it by handling it by delegate methods of `pickerview`.

**Second** : via `TextField` (Your recommended)

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
    if(textField == Your_textfield)
  {
        Your_viewcontroller *vc= [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Your_viewcontroller_identifier"];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the textField and use the following Code:

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if ([textField.text isEqualToString:@""])
    {
        return YES;
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog (@"Go To View Controller");
        [self changeView];
        return NO;
    }

}
-(void)changeView
{
    secondScreen *obj =[[secondScreen alloc]init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:obj animated:YES];

}
```

This code would move you to your second View if the textField already contains text.

In your second view you can define a button like this and set its action to a function as below to return to your previous ViewController

```
-(void) crossButtonPressed{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

I hope this helps you out.

Comment: how you suppose to move another vc with that class object `obj` ?

Comment: Well secondScreen.h is the header file of the secondViewController and obj is just an instance of it which is used to push to the other secondScreenViewController and in this case I am not using Xib and storyboard

Comment: okay then how you creating vc if not using xib of storyboard ?

Comment: by creating a new cocoa file of type UIViewController